# Broadcasting a single value Spark(python)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, broadcast

Lets say I am having the following list and a single value:

```py
alist = [1,2,3,4,5]
alistRDD = sc.parallelize(alist)
single_value = 3
```

and I got the following function:

```py
def a_fun(x,y): 
    return x+y
```

And I am doing the following:

```py
alistRDD.map(lambda x:a_fun(x,single_value))
```

So I am using for this function as second argument the `single_value`. Does it make sense to broadcast this `single_value` in order to be in all the nodes?

Comment: I think your question is more: does it matter in terms of performance? I think the answer is no

Answer (score 0):

When the driver submit this transformation to the workers it would simply pass the value it self and not the parameter. So from performance perspective it may even be better. There is no value in broadcasting data that is assigned without any logic. You be better simply pass the variable and let the serialization process turn it into the value itself. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: To clarify, from performance perspective it may be better to broadcast a single value?

Comment: No. It would be better to just let it serialize into a value.